# Short to battery & short to ground

Tags: batteries, automotive

In automobile industry, while some of the sensor & valves were connected with electronic control unit, short to battery & short to ground test conditions are taken care against the loads.

What is the reason for this test condition?

Comment: never heard these terms. Can you point at some documentation that says what they mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any wire connecting to a sensor can touch or short with another wire that is battery positive ie 12V+ so the sensor is fed directly from the battery. What will the sensor do in those conditions? Fail open circuit or fail short circuit? If short circuit then will that cause a fire or damage to other wiring? Failing open circuit does not tend to cause wiring damage.

If the sensor wire is shorting to the body or ground, i.e. battery negative then will that damage the sensor or other wiring or the unit supplying the sensor?

All these need to be checked and accounted for, and fuses or current limiters need to be fitted as appropriate.